# Get id of another view in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I have two views, one of them have a search box that includes a button "Search" with `id="search"`. In the second view I want when click in button "Search" make a search. But for this happens I need to get the id. How can do this?

Here the code of my second view, but not works because `#search` is in the first view:

```
ev.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {
        'click #search' : 'searchKey',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the events hash are limited to the views `el`. Hence the event won't be triggered. Access the element Globally and bind the event using jquery in view's initialize.

```
     ev.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
       initialize:function(){
       $('#search').click(this.searchKey);
      }

});
```

Edit : this answer just solves the problem. consider *Peter Wagener* answer.

Answer (score 4):

Globally attaching a `click` listener will work, but the application becomes hard to work with as it grows.  You're better off treating each `View` as a rectangle on the page that *only* knows about things that happen within itself.  When two views need to interact, you need some way to coordinate between them.

One simple suggestion is to use a Model as an event bus between the two views:

```
var ViewWithSearch = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .search' : 'searchKey'
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.eventModel = options.eventModel;
    },

    searchKey: function(event) {
        this.eventModel.trigger('search', event)
    }
});

var ReactingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.listenTo(options.eventModel, 'search', this.onSearch);
    },

    onSearch: function(eventModel, event) {
        console.log("Search was clicked!");
    }
});

var eventModel = new Backbone.Model();

new ViewWithSearch({
    eventModel: eventModel
}).render();

new ReactingView({
    eventModel: eventModel
}).render();
```

This is definitely more complex than the global event, but it also is true to the `MV*` design.  You get a nicely decoupled set of views that don't know anything "outside" of themselves, making them easy to maintain (and test!).

There are lots of libraries out there that provide this sort of functionality; for instance, [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio) is built for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: You can also `eventBus = _.extend({ }, Backbone.Events)` if you just need a global event system without any storage.

Comment: +1 to that comment!  That's actually what I do in some production apps; just didn't want to expand the answer to have to explain `Backbone.Events` too.

Comment: You could also look up Marionette, a lightweight MVC extension of Backbone that adds a Controller to hold these kinds of event handlers, keeping your Models and Views more focused on what they should be doing.